# Failed to create new connection Node JS RethinkDbDash

Tags: python, node.js, rethinkdb, rethinkdbdash

```
Fail to create a new connection for the connection pool. Error:{"msg":"Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:28015\nFull error:\n{\"errno\":\"ECONNREFUSED\",\"code\":\"ECONNREFUSED\",\"syscall\":\"connect\",\"address\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"port\":28015}","message":"Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:28015\nFull error:\n{\"errno\":\"ECONNREFUSED\",\"code\":\"ECONNREFUSED\",\"syscall\":\"connect\",\"address\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"port\":28015}.","isOperational":true}
Server #1 Connected!
Server #2 Connected!
Started Shard #undefined
Fail to create a new connection for the connection pool. Error:{"msg":"Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:28015\nFull error:\n{\"errno\":\"ECONNREFUSED\",\"code\":\"ECONNREFUSED\",\"syscall\":\"connect\",\"address\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"port\":28015}","message":"Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:28015\nFull error:\n{\"errno\":\"ECONNREFUSED\",\"code\":\"ECONNREFUSED\",\"syscall\":\"connect\",\"address\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"port\":28015}.","isOperational":true}
Fail to create a new connection for the connection pool. Error:{"msg":"Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:28015\nFull error:\n{\"errno\":\"ECONNREFUSED\",\"code\":\"ECONNREFUSED\",\"syscall\":\"connect\",\"address\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"port\":28015}","message":"Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:28015\nFull error:\n{\"errno\":\"ECONNREFUSED\",\"code\":\"ECONNREFUSED\",\"syscall\":\"connect\",\"address\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"port\":28015}.","isOperational":true}
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:15232
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
Emitted 'error' event on WebSocket instance at:
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/root/ofBot/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:554:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
  code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '192.xxx.xxx.xxx',
  port: 15232
}
```

Honestly, this source code isn't even mine. I got it from somewhere, and I haven't made any progress so far executing it.
Basically I am asking to be spoon fed with some help as I literally have 0 coding knowledge.

Comment: "*Basically I am asking to be spoon fed with some help as I literally have 0 coding knowledge.*" - We don't really do that here.  You are going to need to provide some more information.

Comment: What kind of information would you like to know?

Comment: About something SPECIFIC you are trying to do.

Comment: I tried running the file megaServer.js with the command "node megaServer.js" than I proceeded executing another command in another terminal "node index.js", and I am facing this error. I am just trying to start up the bot.

Comment: where is the source code? why you add the "python" tag?